# Validating input of empty lines (\n\n)

Tags: c

I need to write a program that reads from stdin and only writes non-empty lines to stdout (i.e. lines that only contain \n). For example, if the stdin was:

```
1

2

\n

3
```

The output would be:

```
1

2

3
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main()

{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    char *p;

    printf ("Please enter some lines of text\n");

    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n", buf);
        /*
         *  Remove newline character
         */
        if ((p = strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL)
            *p = '\0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way that I can loop the program around though, so that even if a blank line is entered, the user can still keep inputting?

Comment: I'm not sure your program matches your description (and since the program has syntax problems, it's hard to know if what you want is what the program looks like it might be doing or what you put in the question). The biggest confusing thing is that the program appears to only ever read one line of text, so there's not much opportunity for more than one '\n' to be read in.

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework. If my assumption is correct, please go ahead and edit your post to include the `homework` tag.

Comment: Thanks - I've included a homework tag.

Comment: @AngelaSmith: I'd suggest taking a first step of reading the input line-by-line and simply writing out back out unchanged. That should be a relatively simple task, but there are a couple things that can be tricky to get right (EOF handling for one).  Once you have that working, it should be very straightforward to add the logic to skip the empty lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    printf ("Please enter some lines of text\n");

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL){
        if(*buf != '\n')
            printf("%s", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework?

If not, grep will do what you want:

```
grep --invert-match '^$' yourfile
```

That is, match any lines that aren't start of line (`^`) followed immediately by end of line (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

So, the `if` statement is for a one time block of code, you need a loop statement instead. You can even use the same condition. There are some other small changes you need as well, but once you figure out what type of loop you need, you should be mostly there.

Comment: I know it's not ideal and that I am supposed to find the answer myself, but is there any way that you could show me the solution? I have read K&Rs book and probably every relevant C article online and I still cannot, for the life of me, work out the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to do it in C only. Then, you can use UNIX and Perl to solve your problem

**Input**

```
1
2
\n
3
```

**UNIX Solution**

```
$> grep -v '\n' Input
```

**Perl Solution**

```
@text = `cat /home/Input`;
foreach my $no_only (@text)
{
        if ($no_only =~ /\d/)
        {
                print "$no_only\n";
        }
}
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
```